# Mendeley search by query parameters

Tags: mendeley

Mendeley has a Catalog Search -> Search by query API that looks like the following: curl 'https://api.mendeley.com/search/catalog?query=polar+bears&limit=3' ...

The API Reference documentation says: "Retrieve documents which match general query terms."

I am wondering what general query terms (besides 'query=xxx' and 'limit=y') are available.  I tried including some of the returned fields as parameters, e.g. year=2002, which was seemingly ignored, and title=xxx, which provoked the error: "Invalid parameters supplied"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all documented on the [Swagger page](https://api.mendeley.com/apidocs/docs#!/catalog_0/search).

You can use title, and you can also search by year using `min_year` and `max_year`.

Comment: Thanks!  In experimenting with the parameters, I find that I get an "Invalid parameters supplied" return if I use the query=xxx parameter with title=yyy and the same if I use query=xxx with author=yyy or query=xxx with abstract=yyy.  But query=xxx works fine with min_year, max_year, and limit.  So, it seems that some combinations are ok while others are not supported.

Comment: The parameters `title`, `author`, `source` and `abstract` are all incompatible with `query`. You have to specify *either* query, *or* at least one of the other four.